# TLSharp Send message to a group

Tags: c#, telegram

```
//get user dialogs
var dialogs = await client.GetUserDialogsAsync() as TLDialogs;

//find channel by title
var chat = dialogs.Chats
                  .Where(c => c.GetType() == typeof(TLChat))
                  .Cast<TLChat>()
                  .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Title == "zgzxbhsrbhdrbh");

//send message
await client.SendMessageAsync(new TLInputPeerChannel() { ChannelId = chat.Id }, 
                                                         "OUR_MESSAGE");
```

I`m trying this code, but it returns me InvalidOperationException: CHANNEL_INVALID. Can someone help?

Comment: it seems that you have missed the access_hash in your TLInputPeerChannel instantiation.

Comment: I can get the acess_hash only if I using TLGroup (no the TLChat) :c

Answer (score 1):

You were quite right.

```
//Get dialogs
 var dialogs = await client.GetUserDialogsAsync();

//get user chats 
   var chats = ((TeleSharp.TL.Messages.TLDialogsSlice)dialogs).Chats;

//find channel by title
   var tlChannel = chats.Where(_ => _.GetType() == typeof(TLChannel))
                        .Select(_=>(TLChannel)_)
                        .Where(_=>_.Title.Contains("<Channel-Name>"))
                        .FirstOrDefault();
//send message
    await client.SendMessageAsync(new TLInputPeerChannel()
                    { ChannelId = tlChannel.Id, AccessHash =(long)tlChannel.AccessHash },
                    "OUR_MESSAGE");
```

Comment: Consider adding more description to this question and explain why you've done this and how it works. Otherwise it's much harder for people to derive meaning from this.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between sending to a group and sending to a channel
In your code, at the end of it, you called a command to send to a channel, and in the first one, you specified the type as a group. This is the latest exception. You can try this code and, God willing, the problem will be solved.

```
//get user dialogs
        var dialogs = (TLDialogsSlice)await client.GetUserDialogsAsync();
        //find channel by title
        var chat = dialogs.Chats
          .Where(c => c.GetType() == typeof(TLChat))
          .Cast<TLChat>()
          .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Title == "zgzxbhsrbhdrbh");

        //send message
        await client.SendMessageAsync(new TLInputPeerChat() { ChatId = chat.Id }, "OUR_MESSAGE");
```